# Mailchimp already subscribed error resend "Welcome Email" delivery of email

Tags: mailchimp

Hope you can help on this one. I want to resend the welcome email to anyone that enters email submit on my mailchimp form. This includes new subscribers and existing subscribers that re-enter their email addresses on the mailchimp form. Hope that makes sense. Any help appreciated. I'm new but quick study to the html and php coding world so if you can step thru for me.

The landing page is: http://www.plannerpress.net/jgh7atu/

Comment: Hi there! What have you tried so far? People will generally be more helpful if you're having a specific problem and you show what you have done so far.

Comment: I have tried meta refresh redirect but that did not work it was stuck in a loop of sorts. Not sure if I can do this thru Mailchimp free or if I have to go pro (which I don't want to yet as the list is still small).. Used this: 

<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0"; url="http://www.domain.com/redirectlink" EMAIL="*|EMAIL|*">

Comment: I also found a site called Mandrill.com that is a mailchimp company that deals in integrations Not sure if that is what I 'need' to use or if even elpful in my weird case... Like to do this in a coding way I suppose...

Comment: Can anyone help on this? Still looking for a solution, thx

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems pretty unlikely that you'd actually want to send a welcome email multiple times. It seems more likely that you're putting other content in the welcome email and trying to use it cleverly to achieve some other goal. I'd focus on that goal instead of the current implementation you're working on.

The answer to your question, though is that this isn't possible directly. Your two options are 1) delete the subscriber and then re-subscribe them or 2) use automations to send the email you really want to send when you want to send it.

I'm not 100% sure #1 will work, and even if it does, you'll lose user activity for those users when they re-subscribe. I'd work on #2 if I were you.

Comment: Thank you yes I am sending them a coupon and want the functionality that when they request it (by putting in their email), they get the current week's coupon on demand by getting an email. It just works out that mailchimp has that final elcome email for new subscribers, but for existing subscribers re-entering their email it does not work.

Automation will work but not sure how to do that and if there is a free option to do that. ALso, will the site: mandrill.com do anything for me for free (i think it is a mailchimp company that also has free until 12000 email per month..)

Comment: Yes, this seems like a better use for Mandrill than MailChimp unless you're already sending them marketing emails.